# .NET bug when converting float to integer?

Tags: .net, floating-point

Check it out: this little .NET Console Program yields interesting results...notice how I'm converting a float to an integer in two different ways:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CastVsConvert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int newWidth = 0;
            CalculateResizeSizes(600, 500, out newWidth);
        }

        static void CalculateResizeSizes(int originalWidth, int maxWidth, out int newWidth)
        {
            float percentage = 1.0F;
            percentage = maxWidth / (float)originalWidth;

            newWidth = (int)((float)originalWidth * percentage);
            int newWidthConvert = Convert.ToInt32((float)originalWidth * percentage);

            Console.Write("Percentage: {0}\n", percentage.ToString());
            Console.Write("Cast: {0}\n", newWidth.ToString());
            Console.Write("Convert: {0}\n", newWidthConvert.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the output for "Cast" and "Convert" to be the same, but they're not...here's the output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Scott\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CastVsC
onvert\CastVsConvert\bin\Debug>CastVsConvert.exe
Percentage: 0.8333333
Cast: 499
Convert: 500
```

Does anybody know why .NET is returning different values here?

Answer (score 14):

Its not a bug, `cast` truncates, `convert` rounds.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104063/systemconverttoint-vs-int)

Answer (score 5):

The cast is chopping off the portion of the number after the decimal point while the conversion is rounding.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs for the return value of [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/303w38b8.aspx):

> *value* rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is halfway
>   between two whole numbers, the even
>   number is returned; that is, 4.5 is
>   converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted
>   to 6.

Casting doesn't round up - it just truncates. The result of the multiplication is very slightly under 500, so casting will truncate that to 499 whereas Convert.ToInt32 will round it up to 500.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra, hidden cast that's probably causing this.  For example, if you use this instead of a recalculation:

```
int newWidthConvert = Convert.ToInt32(newWidth);
```

You'll get the same result.  What's happening becomes more clear when you use Reflector to peek at `Convert.ToInt32(float)`:

```
public static int ToInt32(float value)
{
    return ToInt32((double) value);
}
```

There's a hidden cast to `Double`.

If you add a couple of lines to investigate, then use the debugger to take a look, you'll see what happens:

```
float newWidth1 = ((float)originalWidth * percentage);
double newWidth2 = ((float)originalWidth * percentage);
```

`double` is more precise and saves the value as 499.999999 and a few more decimal digits.  `float` is less precise and stores 500.0.  The integer conversion truncates the decimal part, so you end up with 500 or 499 based on the intermediate cast.  When you call `Convert.ToInt32()`, the result is already cast to a `float` so you get the `Double` representation of 500.0.  Personally I prefer always using `double` when I can.