# How can I get the return value from my stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, return-value

Here's my SQL:

```
IF (SELECT Status FROM dbo.Coupon WHERE Guid = @pGuid) = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        dbo.Coupon

    SET
        Status = @pStatus   

    WHERE
        Guid = @pGuid

    RETURN 0    
END

ELSE

RETURN 1;
```

And here's my C#:

```
try
            {
                DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("upd_Coupon_p");
                db.AddInParameter(command, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
                db.AddInParameter(command, "@pStatus", DbType.Byte, 1);
                ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(command);
             }
```

How can I get the return value of 0 or 1 inside of my code?

Comment: How can I get the return value from my stored procedure?

Comment: is db an instance of a custom database class?  Oh wait!  You're using the EL!

Answer (score 5):

You add a return value parameter, like this:

For SqlCommand:

```
parameters.Add("@retValue", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

For the EL, you'd want to use db.AddParameter() and specify ParameterDirection.ReturnValue.

In addition, as long as row count is on in your database, for the update you are performing you could use the result from ExecuteNonQuery() that tells you how many rows were affected on an update/insert/delete/etc.  That way you could handle if rows affected was 0 (couldn't find any)

Comment: The answer here fleshes it out a bit more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520735/can-you-use-cmd-executescalar-when-the-sproc-uses-return-value

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, so basically just use ReturnValue, but the other parts may be useful.

```
            var retparam = new SqlParameter("@return", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue };
            comm.Parameters.Add(retparam);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int ret = 0;
            if (retparam == null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("retparam was null");
            }
            else if (retparam.Value == null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
               // use reparam.Value.ToString()
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

What is DbCommand.ExecuteDataSet() and why don't you use ExecuteScalar()?

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable as output and get it inside the call function of Data Access section.

see the code below,

In the stored procedure,

```
  @ReturnStatus int output //inside your stored procedure argument section
```

In the Data Access section use the following,

```
   AddOutParameter(.....);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: There's no need to add an output parameter if all you're interested in is the return value - that's accessible as detailed in the other answers using the returnValue enum. Admittedly there's nothing wrong with what you've suggested, it's just a bit unnecessary.