# How to return a bool using execute scalar

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure returning a boolean varialbe :

Here is my C# code that works when I try to return an int variable.But it doesnt work when I try it for bool.

```
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("spGetConfigureAlerts");
            object o = db.ExecuteScalar(dbCommand);
            bool item = o == null ? 0 : (bool)o;
            return item;
```

I have it as shown above , but on line three it says that :

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'bool'
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: You must share your SP also.

Comment: use `false` instead of `0`.

Comment: Note that your stp should select rather than return the value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520735/can-you-use-cmd-executescalar-when-the-sproc-uses-return-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you use `0` at all if you want to initialize a `bool` variable?

```
bool item = (o == null || DBNull.Value == o) ? false : (bool)o;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool item = o == null ? false : (bool)o;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool item = o == null ? false : (bool)o;
```