# Any performance difference between int.Parse() and Convert.Toint()?

Tags: c#, performance

Is there any significant advantages for converting a string to an integer value between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32() ?

```
string stringInt = "01234";

int iParse = int.Parse(stringInt);

int iConvert = Convert.ToInt32(stringInt);
```

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104063/system-convert-toint-vs-int) asking about casting vs Convert but I think this is different, right?

Comment: This is differen't, yes.

Comment: I would love to find out about this as well.

Comment: Ack, I didn't get to find out if there is any significant performance differences between two yet!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When passed a string as a parameter, Convert.ToInt32 calls int.Parse internally. So the only difference is an additional null check.

Here's the code from .NET Reflector

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: The question asks for a "Performance" differences.  Will that "null check" incur any performance penalties?

Comment: Sung: Of course. A null check is another operation that has to be done. While it may be extremely small, there will be a performance penalty.

Answer (score 17):

For what its worth:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int iterations = 1000000;
            string val = "01234";

            Console.Write("Run 1: int.Parse() ");
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            DoParse(iterations, val);
            TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - start;
            Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

            Console.Write("Run 1: Convert.ToInt32() ");
            start = DateTime.Now;
            DoConvert(iterations, val);
            duration = DateTime.Now - start;
            Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

            Console.Write("Run 2: int.Parse() ");
            start = DateTime.Now;
            DoParse(iterations, val);
            duration = DateTime.Now - start;
            Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

            Console.Write("Run 2: Convert.ToInt32() ");
            start = DateTime.Now;
            DoConvert(iterations, val);
            duration = DateTime.Now - start;
            Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

            Console.Write("Run 3: int.Parse() ");
            start = DateTime.Now;
            DoParse(iterations, val);
            duration = DateTime.Now - start;
            Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

            Console.Write("Run 3: Convert.ToInt32() ");
            start = DateTime.Now;
            DoConvert(iterations, val);
            duration = DateTime.Now - start;
            Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void DoParse(int iterations, string val)
        {
            int x;
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                x = int.Parse(val);
            }
        }

        static void DoConvert(int iterations, string val)
        {
            int x;
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                x = Convert.ToInt32(val);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Result of 1,000,000 iterations of each:

```
Run 1: int.Parse() Duration: 312.5ms
Run 1: Convert.ToInt32() Duration: 328.125ms
Run 2: int.Parse() Duration: 296.875ms
Run 2: Convert.ToInt32() Duration: 312.5ms
Run 3: int.Parse() Duration: 312.5ms
Run 3: Convert.ToInt32() Duration: 312.5ms
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Happy 10k :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in the way both handles NULL value.

When encountered a NULL Value, Convert.ToInt32 returns a value 0.
On other hand,Parse is more sensitive and expects a valid value. 
So it would throw an exception when you pass in a NULL.

Answer (score 1):

See [this discussion for details.](http://julien.jacobs.free.fr/netshare/2006/08/int32parse-vs-converttoint.html)

Convert.ToInt32 won't throw as often (if stringInt == null, it returns 0 instead of throwing an exception), but has a slight bit more overhead since it's doing a few extra checks, then calling int.Parse internally.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the code below and the result was that int.parse is slower than convert.toint32.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(TimeConvertTo());
        Console.WriteLine(TimeParse());
    }

    static TimeSpan TimeConvertTo() {
        TimeSpan start = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++) {
            Convert.ToInt32("01234");
        }
        return DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Subtract(start);
    }

    static TimeSpan TimeParse() {
        TimeSpan start = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++) {
            int.Parse("01234");
        }
        return DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Subtract(start);
    }
```

Comment: how is that possible, may be 99999999 is too less a number to get a valid result

Answer (score 1):

There are some performance implications as others have mentioned. If you look at the test code and performance stats [from this website](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int):

- Int.Parse() and Int.TryParse() generally perform faster as the number of conversions you're performing increases.
- Convert.ToInt() seems to perform best with a low number of conversions
- The overall *fastest* way to convert a string to an int (assuming no exceptions) regardless of the number of conversions you need to perform is:

_

```
y = 0; //the resulting number from the conversion
//loop through every char in the string, summing up the values for the final number
for (int i = 0; i < s[x].Length; i++) 
    y = y * 10 + (s[x][i] - '0');
```

Comment: That was really educating. For reference, look here for ParseInt32 for the int.Parse source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,04291cc3a0b10032

Answer (score 0):

Both of the them are slow. If you know the exact format of input string and care about speed, I suggest you write the convert function by yourself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).