# What is the Difference Between Convert.Int32() and Int32.Parse()?

Tags: .net

I Have some confusion while using Convert.Int32() and int32.Parse().
When we use Convert.Int32() or int32.Parse()...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert.ToInt32() will attempt to convert anything - be it char, double, object, what have you - into an Int32.  Int32.Parse() only works for strings.

EDIT: In response to OP's comment, I have a quote taken [from this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1ca53a60-e094-4073-ab33-27cca0bdbad4):

> Basically the Convert class makes it
>   easier to convert between all the base
>   types.
>
> The Convert.ToInt32(String,
>   IFormatProvider) underneath calls the
>   Int32.Parse. So the only difference is
>   that if a null string is passed to
>   Convert it returns 0, whereas
>   Int32.Parse throws an
>   ArgumentNullException.
>
> It is really a matter of choice
>   whichever you use.

Comment: You might also want to note caveats.. for instance:  `Convert.ToInt32('9')` will result in 57 (the ascii value) where as `Convert.ToInt32("9")` will result in 9. If there is an implicit conversion then the conversion will be used.

Comment: Hi,Matthew. If I have a string value and need to convert it into the integer value then which is best to use...

Comment: If you have a string use parse or tryParse.

Comment: @Vijj int.TryParse(...) if you cannot guarantee your strings are integers.

Comment: @@ Vijj Go out for a walk , than come back and checkout the relative similar entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641304/any-performance-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint :)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Matthew's answer.

Convert.ToInt32 allows for user defined conversions in an extendable manner.  For any non-predefined conversion (mostly primitives), The Convert class will check and see if the type implements IConventible and if so use it to allow the object to define it's own conversion to Int32 (and many other types).

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToInt32` will convert `null` into `0`; `Int32.Parse` will throw an exception if you pass it `null`.  Also, [as Matthew Jones said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500425/what-is-the-difference-between-convert-int32-and-int32-parse/1500437#1500437), `Int32.Parse` only works for strings.

See [this article](http://julien.jacobs.free.fr/netshare/2006/08/int32parse-vs-converttoint.html#links) for more information

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN Parse() is used for string to int where Convert is much more versatile for conversions.

Int32.Parse()

[Convert.Int32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32.aspx) should be your main choice