# Which conversion method is better?

Tags: c#

Convert.ToInt32 or Int.Parse which is better and why? Is there any specific condition where i can use these two?.

Comment: Int32.TryParse(..) is best - I think this question is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably you're asking about the `Convert.ToInt32` which takes a string. In that case, it simply calls `int.Parse` internally, so there's no real difference except that `Convert` gracefully handles `null` by returning 0.

Answer (score 2):

Convert.ToInt32 internally calls Int.Parse with a null check. So the Null check is extra and does not throw in case of a Null parameter.

You can refer to this question here: [Any performance difference between int.Parse() and Convert.Toint()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641304/any-performance-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint)

Answer (score 1):

One of them calls the other (though I can't remember which is which ATM), so there's no practical difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

From [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

So calling int.Parse() would be a little quicker.

Comment: Not measurably. It's misleading to new developers to imply such operations are even worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect `null` to ever be passed as the argument, use `int.Parse`, since then you'll be alerted via an exception when something *does* go wrong.